# How to read event only once in Azure Event Hub

Tags: events, offset, azure-eventhub, event-processor-host

I want to read events only once from Azure Event hub so that event gets processed only once.
But while reading these events getting same event in all partitions.

Tech Stack - Spring boot to read events via

```
EventProcessorHost host = EventProcessorHost.EventProcessorHostBuilder
            .newBuilder(EventProcessorHost.createHostName(hostNamePrefix), 
consumerGroupName)
            .useAzureStorageCheckpointLeaseManager(storageConnectionString, storageContainerName, null)
            .useEventHubConnectionString(eventHubConnectionString.toString(), eventHubName)
            .build();
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you say you received the same message in different partitions? That is not possible. Are yiu sure the message is sent  just once? Could it be that multiple messages are sent with the same content?

Comment: Yes, just double checked, its per event per partition.
But i want to process only once same event.

Comment: How do you tell an event is same as the other? Do you have some unique identifier to compare?

Comment: No, there is no identifier to compare.
That's what i am looking for, How to read event only once in Azure Event Hub

Answer (score 0):

You can create up to `32` partition on Eventhub but when you send a message that will go only on single partition (if you would not put `partition-id`, Eventhub will send message to random partition )

> Event Hubs retains data for a configured retention time that applies across all partitions in the event hub. Events expire on a time basis; you cannot explicitly delete them. Because partitions are independent and contain their own sequence of data, they often grow at different rates. [partitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability#partitions)

maybe issue with your code, To confirm this behaviour you can use Microsoft [ServiceBusExplorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) to send and receive messages from Eventhub. When you will create Eventhub listener through Service bus you can receive partition-id and messages in real-time.